# Persist a http connection for longer time with php?

Tags: php, wordpress, http

I am working on a project where I am

1. processing some SVG files with Imagick and converting them to png
2. save them in a folder
3. Zipping the folder using ZipArchive
4. And in the end echo a JSON string with the direct downloadable link for the UI to consume and start the download.

Currently, I am doing it for around 20 files and it takes 10-11 seconds for the API to run and then echo the reply. But in the future, there might be around 500 images to be processed and zipped. Hence I am afraid that I will get a connection timeout error before all the images are even processed. I am sure there is a future proof way to handle this. I just need a nudge in the right direction.

The constraints I have are -
It has to be in Php. Also, I am not sure if I will be able to run Websockets libraries on the server I own.

PS. I know it's probably not that important by I am using WordPress.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use an asynchronous approach. Send the data to the backend with some identification. Then in backend you run a process and save data/response to some database with the identification. In frontend you keep doing every couple seconds a request to the backend to see if the job is already done.

Comment: You need to look into queue systems which allow you to process data separate from server calls. Than, when a job is done notify user via websockets. I'm not sure if WordPress will be able to do this, I know Laravel does it very well but that might be a big change for you. With regards to websockets look into services like Pusher.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte do you mean triggering some kind of Cron Job?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman: I don't want to add WebSocket to my project just for this one small thing. So I was looking for some old school workaround. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: @Roy yes, the cronjob would execute some php process that will check if there is pending jobs to execute, then execute it. After that, save that job is done in database. The frontend will do a request every couple seconds to see if the job is done or not.